# Formants extraction from LPC

Tags: filters, z-transform, speech-processing, speech-recognition, lpc

I would like to do formants extraction using LPC. I made the necessary pre-emphasis before feeding the speech samples to the LPC function.

```
N = len(X)
w = np.hamming(N)
x1 = X * w
x1 = lfilter([1], [1., 0.63], x1)
```

```
ncoeff= int(2 + Fs/1000)
lpc=librosa.lpc(x1,order=ncoeff)
```

Solving the poles from the all-poles system-Transfer function for speech,

$$ H(z) = \frac{1}{1 - \sum_{i=1}^{p} a_i.z^{-i}} = \frac{1}{A(z)} $$

```
poles = np.roots(lpc)
poles = np.array([r for r in poles if np.imag(r) >= 0])
frequencies = np.arctan2(poles.imag, poles.real) * (Fs / (2 * np.pi))
```

Although the formants F1 and F2 (typical values expected for a given vowel) are indeed present in this array of frequencies, I get undesired low frequencies. Hence, I could not straightaway choose F1 and F2 as first two values. How to make the program choose F1 and F2?